# Dice roll python

Tags: python

Trying to create a program that prints dice roll of 4 dice if the sum is greater then 8 and less then 20.  When i run this i get an infinite loop. I tried setting total = 0 then adding the sum of the 4 dice to total in the while loop but that didnt work.

code:

```
from random import randint

def main():
    total = sum(diRoll())
    while total > 8 and total < 20:
        print(diRoll())




def diRoll():
    dice1 = randint(1, 6)
    dice2 = randint(1, 6)
    dice3 = randint(1, 6)
    dice4 = randint(1, 6)
    diceRolls = dice1, dice2, dice3, dice4
    return sorted(diceRolls)


main()
```

Comment: I have rolled the question back so the answers people provided match. You can add your solution as an answer if you feel the need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, inside your `while` loop, you never set `total` to a new value. So your loop will continue to test against the old value, and thus will never end.

Comment: Either that or it will print the same value over and over.

Comment: No, it will continue to print new values but will not stop if a valid value is found. Try this: while total > 8 and total < 20: total = diRoll(); print(total)

Comment: i think i solved my problem thanks guys. Updated the question with my solution

Comment: @Downvoter My answer is correct, and correctly identifies the cause of the OP's problems, but the OP changed the question with the fixed code (read the above comment, and the question revision history). Just so you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: The *while* will go into an infinite loop but this will print different dice permutations that meet your criteria for total.  If you include the *break* , it will terminate

```
def main():
    while True:
        total = sum(diRoll())
        if total > 8 and total < 20:
            print(diRoll())
            break
```